# how to addcommenter to one file without sending email

Tags: google-apps-script

We have students' attendances files shared with their families (commenter permission only).

It seems that some of the sharings weren't correctly done in the first time, when the script created the files.

So I want to do a bulk re-sharing with them, **but not sending any email**. They are more than than 500 families, and I don't want to disturb or confuse them with a message.

file.addCommenter seems to send an automatic email.

is it possible not to send it?

Thanks,

Enrique

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest thing to do it to move all these files in a folder and manually assign the right permissions to this folder.

This way you control easily the common access rights of all the included files.

A script could help you to move the files, you'll find [a lot of examples of such code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Dmove%20to%20folder) here on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Sorry, Serge, but I am afraid I didn't state the point clearly enough. Each student's attendance is registered in a different file (spreadsheed), and must be shared ONLY WITH HIS/HER PARENTS' ACCOUNT.

Comment: Ah?  Well you're right, in that case it's indeed not a solution... I'll leave it there in case someone else misunderstands :-)